# Preloading approx. 10 images (8Mpix) in Java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, preload

I want to preload (load into memory) about 10 jpg pictures (size 3264px x 2448px). Each image filesize is ~3MB. I've tried to load them into ArrayList of BufferedImage but I get OutOfMemoryError Exception (Java heap space). How to cope with it?

Comment: What is your maximum permitted memory size?

Comment: Even uncompressed this should be around 24 - 32 MB x 10 which is up to 320 MB.  Most PCs should have more than enough memory.  Are you using a memory limited device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..any possibility to store image in compressed form?

Sure, load them as byte arrays & keep a reference to each (3 Meg) array.  As you require each actual image, stamp it out to an image by wrapping it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use that as the source to `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

That would come to around 30 Meg for the 10 `byte[]`, and 32<sup>1</sup> meg for each realized image.

1. AFAIU JPEG images cannot have transparency, so a 32 Meg ARGB image would be 24 Meg as RGB.

Answer (score 2):

> Each image filesize is ~3MB. I've tried to load them into ArrayList of
>   BufferedImage but I get OutOfMemoryError Exception (Java heap space).
>   How to cope with it?

Each *compressed* image size is 3MB.  As you wrote in your title, 3264*2448 is 7 990 272 pixels (about 8Mpix).  Using the common ARGB that's 32 bits per pixel, or about 32 MB per picture.

If you want to preload these 10 pictures uncompressed (for example in ten `BufferedImage`), you'll need 320 MB of memory for these 10 pictures only.

So you'd need to run your java application with more memory.

Comment: I know that. So, there is no any possibility to store image in compressed form?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, if you are absolutely sure that the best solution to your problem is to store your images in memory, you can adjust the java heap size using the -Xmx (max heap size) and possibly the -Xmn (initial heap size) parameters that are passed in when you start the JVM (the java or javaw command). For your problem, perhaps 512 meg would be good (-Xmx512m). The default max size is 64 meg, which is why you are running out of memory For more info, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html

Having said that, although 320 MB is not an outrageous amount of memory in these days of multi gigabyte computerss, it is certainly not insignificant. Unless you are doing something that requires very fast rendering, such as animation, I would think leaving the images as files would be fine in many cases.

And, the compromise solution was suggested above. Covnerting the image files to BufferedImages means you need 320 MB. But, if you store the file contents itself as a byte arrray, then you will only need 30 MB. To do that

a) Get the file size using the length method of the File object
b) Allocate a byte [] array to that size
c) Use the read method of FileInputStream to read the file into the array

Then, when you want to convert the byte array to a BufferedImage:

a) Use a ByteArrayInputStream to convert the byte array to a InputStream
b) Use ImageIo.read to convert the InputStream to a BufferedImage

However, I am not sure that the compromise solution will be preceived by your users as being that much faster than simply reading directly from the file. File IO is pretty fast these days.